# How to trigger DHCP request and inspect the reply from DHCP server

Tags: dhcp-server, sniffing, dhcp-option

Is it possible to trigger a DHCP request from my DHCP server and then sniff and inspect the whole DHCP reply from the server to see what options/parameters it sends to the clients?

Comment: You don't mention operating system, but I've used this [DHCP Test Client](http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/10/dhcp-test-client/) to do it in Windows.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for, I just needed a quick tool to see what does my DHCP say about **default** **gw**, and what options does it send. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Windows: Run Wireshark. Do ipconfig /release followed by ipconfig /renew on the command line.